# How to rebase branch from develop to another new branch create from develop?

Tags: git, backlog

[image]
I want to create experimental branch from develop and rebase feature branch that has 2 commits to it but something I make mistake and the result is like in this question : [How to remove first commit of a specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093192/how-to-remove-first-commit-of-a-specific-branch?noredirect=1#comment122115409_69093192) 
Now I can fix by the solution of Mr.Gaël J. and want to redo again.
Is below command will achieve what I want? Thank you in advance.

```
===== Create experimental branch =====
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git checkout -b experimental
**Add Note.txt and put some text
git add -A
git commit -m "Experimental branch commit for experimental development"
git push origin experimental

===== Rebase feature branch to experimental branch =====
git checkout feature
git rebase --onto experimental develop feature
git push -f origin feature
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: yes, your command sequence is correct.

You can shorten it slightly using `git rebase experimental`.

#### Long

Use `git checkout` or `git switch` to select the commit at the tip of `develop`:

```
git switch develop
```

You now have that commit as the *current* commit, with that branch name as the *current branch name;* I like to draw this as:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

where the uppercase letters stand in for commit hash IDs.

Now you can create a new branch name `experimental`, and make it the current branch:

```
git switch -c experimental    # or git checkout -b experimental
```

producing:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, experimental (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

A new commit you make now advances the name `experimental`:

```
          K   <-- experimental (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

It's now necessary to copy commits `I` and `J` to new, slightly-different commits that use commit `K` as the parent of the copy of `I`, and use the copy of `I` as the parent of `J`.  The `git rebase` command does this kind of copying.

If you give `git rebase` a *`branch`* argument, it runs an initial `git switch` (or `git checkout`) on that argument.  I find this unwise (there's a bug recently discovered on the Git mailing list, in this area) and prefer to do my own separate `git switch`, but you can run:

```
git rebase --onto experimental develop feature
```

to eliminate the separate `git checkout feature` step.  I wouldn't, as I said; I would run `git switch feature` first.

The set of commits that `git rebase` will copy starts with a list of commits as generated by `git log` or `git rev-list`:

```
git rebase [--onto <target>] <upstream>
```

uses the current branch as the source of these commits, and `upstream..HEAD` as the initial list of commits that might potentially be copied.<sup>1</sup>

Since your *`upstream`* argument is either `develop` or `experimental`, the list will be generated by:

```
git log develop..HEAD
```

or:

```
git log experimental..HEAD
```

If you try both commands at this point in the process, you will see that they *produce the same output*.  The reason is that the *left* side of the two-dot operator, `A..B`, tells Git *what commits **not** to use*.  The *right* side tells Git *what commits to use, minus any overridden by the left side*.  Each of these operations works by finding the *last* commit, as named by the hash ID or branch name or `HEAD` name, and working backwards.

The *last* commit on `feature` is `J`, and the next-to-last is `I`, and the one behind that is `H`, and so on.  The exclusion list either starts at `K`, then works back to `H`, and continues backwards from there, or it starts at `H` and works backwards from there.  Commit `K` isn't in the *inclusion* list, so if it is in the *exclusion* list, this is "free": nothing happens one way or another.

This means you can use either `experimental` or `develop` as the *`upstream`* argument to `git rebase`.  Both have the same effect.

If you use the `--onto` argument to `git rebase`, the commit hash ID or name you supply after the literal word `--onto` sets the target for the rebase operation.  If you *omit* it, the *`upstream`* sets the target.<sup>2</sup>  The *`target`* that you want in this case is `experimental`.

Since `experimental` works as an *`upstream`* argument, the command:

```
git rebase experimental
```

suffices, and you don't need a separate `--onto`.

The `git rebase` process will now run, copying each commit one at a time, in the correct order, using Git's internal *detached HEAD* mode:

```
            I'  <-- HEAD
           /
          K   <-- experimental
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

after copying `I` to `I'`, and then:

```
            I'-J'  <-- HEAD
           /
          K   <-- experimental
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

after copying `J` to `J'`.  *Merge conflicts* can occur during the copying of each commit, but if they don't, Git will handle this all on its own.  Finally, once both commits are copied, Git will yank the branch name `feature` over to point to the last-copied commit, and re-attach the special name `HEAD`:

```
            I'-J'  <-- feature (HEAD)
           /
          K   <-- experimental
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J   ???
```

and the rebase is complete.

---

<sup>1</sup>Specific commits may sometimes be *subtracted away* from this list, during or after generating the list.  In your case, none will be subtracted away, so we get to ignore this, and just use the list that you'll see if you run `git log`.

<sup>2</sup>There's another trick involving `--fork-point` if you omit both names, but let's not get into that as it gets complicated.